# Android Dalvik Debugger not always attaching when running ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, debugging, testing

I am using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class to implement test cases for my android app. When I running it usually everything is ok, but when I want to run it in debug mode is not always attach debugger. I mean there is some chance that debugger will be attached but not more than 10%.

I am using API level 8, Windows 7x64, 
Eclipse: Version: Helios Service Release 2/Build id: 20110218-0911

It happened to me on Samsung Galaxy s2, also on LGP500.

It happened to anyone else?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing all eclipse instances, but one helps in 95% of cases.
If it's not helping, restarting adb server or restarting device will do the trick